# get SharedPreference value on android phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

In my application I save data on SharedPreferences.

Here is my code

```
public void initUserData(Context context, String pKey1, String pKey2, long id) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());

         prefs.edit().putString("key1", pKey1).commit();
         prefs.edit().putString("key2", pKey2).commit();
        prefs.edit().putLong("user.id", id).commit();
    }
```

How could I get SharedPreferences values using phonegap? I mean get data using JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

There is a phonegap plugin which enables you to use android's sharedpreferences. Have a look at this: https://github.com/macdonst/AppPreferences

Answer (score 2):

phone gap itself supports shared preference no need to use android coding for that. see docs.phonegap.com

Comment: as far as I know phonegap does support w3c strogage instead of  sharedpreferences,